# Access to the elements of the page in the Page-Worker

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I've created a page-worker in the extension

```
dup = pageWorker.Page({
    contentScript: "self.port.on('alert', function(message) {"+
        "console.log(message);"+
        "document.querySelector('.test-element').title = message;"+
    "});",
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    contentURL: "http://example.com/Licznik-beta/addon.html"
});
```

In "`contentScript`" I can relate to "`document`".
But I can not relate to the `window`, or function, or variable.
`console.log(window)` in `contentScript` return `"TypeError: cyclic object value timers.js:43"`.

I do not understand how it works.
Can someone explain to me?

How to change it?

EDIT

I've added a few lines to the test:

```
self.port.on('addon-licznik', function () {

    console.log(document);
    console.log(window); //  TypeError: cyclic object value   timers.js:43
    runFromAddon(); // ReferenceError: runFromAddon is not defined   timers.js:43

});
```

Function: `runFromAddon();` Of course there is.

Second test:

```
function funSet (tresc) {
    var addonScript = document.querySelector(".addon-script");
    if ( addonScript != undefined ) {
        document.querySelector('head').removeChild( addonScript );
    }
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.className = "addon-script";
    script.textContent = tresc;
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script);
}

function marmo (message) {
    console.log(message);

    funSet("console.log(window); runFromAddon();");
}


self.port.on('addon-licznik', marmo);
```

It works well.

```
Window → http://example.com/Licznik-beta/addon.html
runFromAddon-Log
```

Comment: Use a `contentScriptFile` instead of a `contentScript`. Then you can see what line exactly is causing the problem.

Comment: I've added a few lines to the test.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing the HTML yourself, then use `addon` instead of `self` and attach the script to the page using `<script></script>` instead of `contentScript(File)`. See [Scripting trusted page content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker#Scripting_trusted_page_content).

If you're not writing the HTML, then see [Communicating with Page Scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Communicating_With_Other_Scripts#Page_Scripts).

Comment: Well and running, thanks. ;)

Previously I messed something I could not do that.

Comment: Did not work.

`Object { name: "RequirementError", message: "The `contentScriptFile` option must be a local URL or an array of URLs." }`

Comment: Are you writing your own HTML or no?

Comment: Yes. This is my HTML page.

Comment: Then you should not have a `contentScriptFile` in the page worker constructor. You should just place the scripts in the HTML as I said.